# mysql comparing column aggregates by period side by side

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, 2019q1 and 2019q2, from which I can aggregate a column individually as normal:

```
    mysql> select tname, sum(mhsaved) from teams a, 2019q1 b
    -> where a.tid = b.tid
    -> group by tname order by tname;
+----------------------------+--------------+
| tname                      | sum(mhsaved) |
+----------------------------+--------------+
| AST                        |        95.00 |
| Desktop support            |        23.00 |
| Middleware                 |        38.00 |
| MSSql database             |       351.00 |
| Oracle database            |       609.00 |
| SCM                        |       187.00 |
| Storage                    |        33.00 |
| Systems Engineering        |      2448.00 |
| UNIX Engineering           |        37.00 |
| UNIX Support               |       349.00 |
| Virtualization Engineering |        17.00 |
| Windows server support     |       913.00 |
+----------------------------+--------------+
12 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

I would like to see the results of 2019q1 and 2019q2 side by side; but, just can't quite wrap my mind around the solution.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Doug O'Leary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with subqueries that aggregate from each table.

```
SELECT tname, IFNULL(q1.mhsaved, 0.00) AS mhsaved_q1, IFNULL(q2.mhsaved, 0.00) AS mhsaved_q2
FROM teams AS t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tid, SUM(mhsaved) AS mhsaved
    FROM 2019q1
    GROUP BY tid
) AS q1 ON t.tid = q1.tid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tid, SUM(mhsaved) AS mhsaved
    FROM 2019q2
    GROUP BY tid
) AS q2 ON t.tid = q2.tid
ORDER BY tname
```

Comment: Thank you, sir!  That's it exactly.  I *knew* there was a way to do it; but, my procedural brain wasn't coming anywhere near the right answer.  Thanks again